# Chrome and firefox are rendering incorrectly OPEN SANS web font

Tags: google-chrome, webfonts, text-rendering

since some weeks ago my chrome is rendering bad the google font "open sans", about firefox, it was rendering it bad always,

it is rendering bad in all websites with open sans, and with any weight or size.
I have read something about change chrome://flags/#enable-direct-write but I have not that option
I have cleaned cache,

I have a screnshot showing how it looks in my screen and below how it should look like,

[image: chrome open sans rendering issue]

That screenshot was taken from here: http://104.236.102.187/htmls/open/open.html

currently the version of chrome is 52,
windows 8.1 pro

64bits

Thanks

Comment: I have been facing this since yesterday... Looks like something updated on my win 7

Comment: man, I am the one that asked this, I solved it by installing a old version of chrome (50), and I modified the registry to avoid the automatic update of chrome, however, I know that there is another solution managing the fonts in windows, but I have not tried it yet

Comment: Thanks for the solution buddy. However I will hold on to it as I do not want to downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I tested in latest Windows 10 (64-bit) on latest Firefox 48 and Chrome 52, and do not see like the screenshots above. And the Dev Tools shows `Open Sans` being loaded.

Have you also tried including the various font styles? Since your missing them from your CSS stylesheet `href` on your `<link>`.

It should be something like this so Google knows what font styles to deliver

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic" />
```

Google Web Font page has like 10 font styles for `Open Sans`

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?query=open+sans

Look and see if the various font styles appear, if they do not it could be your graphics card or some kind of **Windows 8 bug** causing that kind of rendering.

**UPDATE**

Also check if `ClearType` is affecting the text in your browser. Try enabling and disabling it and see if you see a difference. In windows search for `Adjust ClearType Text`.

https://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx

Comment: yes, I have tested with all the weights 400,600,300, etc, but the problem is there still,; The only that shows that font correctly is Internet explorer,

Comment: If your on Windows 7, 8 or 10 try `disabling` or `enabling` the Windows feature `ClearType` ... In windows search for `Adjust ClearType Text` .. That could have an impact on the font anti-aliasing that is rendered in the browser. https://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx